# Exponential pdf with $\lambda_i$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

We all know that to find the MLE, you take the pdf, multiply it by itself n times, take the log, and then find the first derivative with respect to the parameter. What if the parameter changes for each observation?

For example, I have the exponential pdf, but lambda changes for every $y_i$, so the pdf is $\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i y}$

Comment: What is the MLE for a sample of size one? Then just note that you really just have $n$ samples of size one.

Comment: 1. With respect to your first sentence, we don't all know that -- for one thing that won't work in general, it only works that way under particular conditions which don't hold in general (though it's sufficient for nice little textbook problems). 2. Please describe the *way* in which the parameter changes -- are the parameters related in some way, for example, or is every parameter just completely unconnected with any other?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.

Let $Y_i$ be a random variable with pmf $p(y|\theta_i)$ where for simplicity $\theta_i$ is a scalar parameter of interest then the log-likelihood for observing $\{Y_i=y_i\}_{i=1}^n$

$$L=\log(\prod_ip(y|\theta))=\sum_i \log(p(y_i|\theta_i))$$

Whenever $Y_i \perp Y_j$, $i \neq j$. You want to find the $\theta$ maximizing this function.

With no more information we can know such a maximum has been found by proper optimality conditions (KKT) conditions such as $p$ being concave function of $\theta_i$ and find

$$\nabla_\theta L:=\vec{0}$$ whith $\vec{0}$ is a $n$-component vector (same dim as $\theta$). Here each component will not influence eachoter as it comes from a sum. So each component is an independent equation

$$\frac{d}{d\theta_i} L = \frac{1}{p(y_i|\theta_i)}\frac{d}{d\theta_i} p(y_i|\theta_i) :=0$$

Now this makes the problem pretty boring. I assume you for example have each parameter as a function of weights and features say $\theta_i = w\cdot x_i$. Now we have a shared parameter and if the $p(y_i|\theta_i)$'s are a for example a concave functions of $w$ the question becomes finding $w$ s.t

$$\nabla_{w} L = \sum_i \nabla_{w} \log(p(y_i|\theta_i)) :=\vec{0}$$
 Where $\vec{0}$ has as many components as w.

To apply this to your problem set $p(y|\theta_i)=\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i y}$

edit: clarified dimensions